# Are there any add-ons for Adobe Dreamweaver, or other applications which execute predictive PHP and/or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm wondering if there are any add-ons available for Adobe Dreamweaver or indeed, other applications, which execute predictive PHP and/or Javascript.

As far as I know, Adobe Dreamweaver has basic support for predictive PHP, with functions like include(), but not for the entire function library, or anywhere near that, and there's no support for predictive Javascript.

If anyone knows of any add-ons that support this or similar functionality, it would be greatly appreciated.

(Even better if it supports the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries as oppose to just Javascript).

:)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Dreamweaver is a great application for 'designing' websites.

If you want to write the technical implementation I would recommend an editor that is attuned to that. I personally use PHPStorm which is great for both PHP and Javascript, my collegues use NetBeans and Eclipse (with PHP/Javascript plugins). If you want something lightweight (no inspection) you could try Notepad++ or EditPlus.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just downloaded the latest NeatBeans IDE, seems like it has all the features I'm looking for.